# What's the need of Bing Webmaster Tools if i have already configured GWT

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

I have an e-commerce site for which the TG is in USA & UK demographics. I've already configured the **Google Analytics** & **Google Webmaster Tools** for the same. All is working well.

Now, my problem is that my client asked me why am I not configuring the **Bing Webmaster Tools** for the site.

I am little confused that what's the need of Bing Webmaster Tools. Is it there any extra helps in the SEO process with Bing Webmaster Tools? Which one is the best tools as per my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as far as most developers concerned, everything related to google is better. Because of scope of users that are using google. Bing is not that popular and big.

Whenever you log in to either Google or Bing Webmaster Tools, you will be greeted with some important stats about your website. No matter what you using, you'll get your data.

Further reading is on [**this link.**](https://builtvisible.com/google-webmaster-tools-vs-bing/)

Comment: Josip, I had already gone through the suggested link while Kristi is already in my network. While question is still same that If my TG is in USA & UK then which one i prefer (GWT or BWT)

Comment: I'd go with GWT. You can achieve exactly the same things in GWT and BWT. But still, I'd go with GWT.